# PC turns on but no display or boot

Tags: boot, display, motherboard, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

**Background**: For starters, my PC is 6 years old and has been working fine with no major hardware problems for that time. It does not undergo any physical stress or damage as it is in a fairly secluded spot under my desk. The failure occurred after I had been gone without using my PC for a week, so I could rule out anything that I did to directly cause it.

**Problem**: My PC turns on normally when I press the power button but my display displays "No HDMI input" or "no signal". I have tested my PC with a second monitor with a different connector with unfortunately the same result. I have plugged in my HDMI input into my GPU and motherboard but to no avail. All hardware seems to run visibly smoothly (getting power, fans spinning). I have tested my GPU on a separate PC and it works fine. My main culprits are my **RAM (2 sticks 4GB DDR4)**, my **CPU (unable to test both, but highly doubt those are the issue)**, my **BIOS chip (ordered a new chip and replaced, STILL same issue; no display)**, my **motherboard (ASRock H110M-HDV)**, or even my **power supply** (all components visibly seem to be getting adequate power). My motherboard does not have a **buzzer/speaker** so I cannot receive beeps from my motherboard, and as my last attempt I plan to get one. Aside from that, I'm stumped. I might even suspect that a power surge from when I was absent from my PC for a week might have fried some components in my motherboard.

Comment: Your mobo might use a series of LED's instead of/in addition to a PC speaker (check your Mobo manual/spec) - but assessing your beep codes should have been one of your first steps. If you don't hear/see a code, then its prob not a RAM/CPU issue. At this stage, it does sound like a mobo failure of some kind.

Comment: @user1138 Unfortunately my mobo does not have LEDs, manual specifies it needs an external speaker, so I'll be waiting for that to arrive